# Javascript framework for Draggable/Droppable tiled interface with pagination and parent/child relatiopnship

Tags: javascript, user-interface, microsoft-metro, tiled

I am building an interface for a website that organizes projects through a tiled interface (more or less like Windows 8 Metro UI). These projects are organized in to groups. Each group will contains subgroups. Each group/sub-group are essentially nothing but a bunch of tiles. A parent/child hierarchy is hence maintained. At the bottom most level, a tile links to a webpage. In terms of functionality, I need to be able to drag a tile from one group and drop it in to another group. In addition, these tiles will be organised as pages with dots at the top to indicate the existence of page. (More like iOS7/Android).

I am sure there are multiple Javascript library that offer this functionality. Can I anybody point me to a library/framework that can help me achieve this